# Scrollable div with html table

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div with scrollbars.

There are some columns in the table with width defined. Till then table headers are fine.

But when I add more columns to grid the header test gets wrapped which i don't want, instead i want horizontal scroll to come.

Normal : 
http://jsfiddle.net/hVRW7/

More Columns : 
http://jsfiddle.net/hVRW7/1/

Comment: the table's cells' contents are breaking as the widths of cells and table conflict (the cells' total width is bigger than the table's width)

Answer (score 1):

The quickest fix is to wrap `<th>`'s labels in spans, then give fixed width to them:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Label1</span></th>
            <th><span>Label2</span></th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Then style as:

```
th span
{

    display:inline-block;
    width:300px; /* or what you wish */

}
```

EDIT [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVRW7/7/).

Comment: upvote for using css and not of creating another conflicting width specification

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have defined a limit of 1024px to the width of the table and then you are defining new columns with a total width that adds up to 1430px.   All browsers are then trying to do their best to make the information fit within the defined width of 1024px.  Since in your given example you are just repeatedly defining the same sets of columns are you sure you need all of them?  If not you should narrow them down to only the ones needed and then determine your actual overall width.  The defined width of the overall table will take precedence over individual widths in determining the maximum width of the table.